# Unable to do a Restore from S3 with RDS SQL Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am attempting to do a restore from S3 in AWS RDS (SQL Server). On the page when I can select the engine, I select SQL Server. But the options to select the Edition are all grayed out and I cannot select one and move on. You can see this from the screen shot below. Note, this does not happen if I simply attempt to create an instance of SQL Server in RDS. I can then select an Edition.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can't do it straight from the console and the Database has to exist already.

> Restoring a Database
>
> To restore your database, you call the rds_restore_database stored
> procedure.
>
> The following parameters are required:
>
> ```
> @restore_db_name – The name of the database to restore.
>
> @s3_arn_to_restore_from – The Amazon S3 bucket that contains the backup file, and the name of the file.
> ```
>
> The following parameters are optional:
>
> ```
> @kms_master_key_arn – If you encrypted the backup file, the key to use to decrypt the file.
> ```
>
> Example Without Encryption
>
> ```
> exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database 
>     @restore_db_name='database_name', 
>     @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/file_name_and_extension';
> ```
>
> Example With Encryption
>
> ```
> exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database 
>         @restore_db_name='database_name', 
>         @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/file_name_and_extension',
>         @kms_master_key_arn='arn:aws:kms:region:account-id:key/key-id';
> ```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html